# How to fetch tasks from android calendar?

Tags: android, calendar, task

I am working on calendar application and i search on this issue "how to get all tasks from android calendar not from google calendar" but i got that it is not possible to fetch tasks from  the calendar.can anybody tell me is it true or false? in case of false please help me to getting tasks from calendar in android.

I am using inbuilt sPlanner not google calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Tasks is **not** part of Calendar. However, you *can* use the [Tasks API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/) to accomplish this under the right circumstances.

By default, there's no identifier for whether or not a Task is associated with your Calendar or not. Two easy ways of creating such an identifier would be to either include some sort of key in the description or create a Task List **exclusively** for Calendar tasks.

If using a key, just retrieve all the tasks and pick only ones containing your key. If using an exclusive Task List, just [list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/v1/reference/tasks/list) all the tasks from the specific list.

Also the calendar being on Android also should not matter here. The Android Calendar app just displays a Google Calendar.